# null pointer exception

Tags: java, jdom

the value memanufacturer is retrieved from xml document using jdom and when this value is assigned to meman array it throws NullPointerException.

```
Element memanufacturer = (Element) row27.get(j9);
        meman[0] = memanufacturer.getValue();
```

what could be the posssible mistake.

Thanks

Comment: meman is null, StackTrace is always nice

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the exception by the second line of code, there are two obvious possibilities:

- `memanufacturer` may be null
- `meman` may be null

We can't tell which of these is the case, but you should be able to.

EDIT: Okay, so now we know that `meman` is null, that's the problem. I would suggest you use a `List<String>` instead:

```
List<String> meman = new ArrayList<String>();

...
Element memanufacturer = (Element) row27.get(j9);
meman.add(memanufacturer.getValue());
```

Using a `List<String>` instead of an array means you don't need to know the size before you start.

However, the fact that you didn't understand the error suggests you should really read a good introductory Java book before going any further with a real project. You should definitely understand how arrays, collections etc work before dealing with XML and the like. It will save you a lot of time in the long run.

Comment: row27.get method can throw NPE just as fine (somewhere inside), but my bet is `meman` for the null

Comment: yes meman is initialized as null i.e String meman[] = null; and there was no issue if meman is simple string variable. but i need it to be an array as in future this piece of code is looped and i want to store all the values while looping.

Comment: @techocrat: Well you're trying to dereference a null variable, so of course it's blowing up. Either you need to create the array beforehand, or preferably change to using a `List<String>` so you don't need to know the size beforehand.

Comment: its not throwing exception but its printing some peculiar values like [Ljava.lang.String;@1bf3d87   i've initialized meman as String meman[] = new String[1];

Comment: @technocrat: Right, so now presumably you're printing `meman` instead of `meman[0]`. As I said in my edit, **learn basic Java before continuing**. You're doing yourself no favours by trying to continue with your current project before you understand the fundamentals of the language.

Comment: Dude you are right. And that is what i'm doing. Iam learning through practicing few of  the examples. And thanks Jon, wishing to meet you some day at GOOGLE.

Comment: @technocrat: I would strongly advise you to stay aware from things like XML while you're learning though. Try some *really simple* programs just to get the hang of Java. Then build up to things like XML.